# Question on the demonstration of Morse theorem

Tags: analysis, morse-theory

We have theorem of Morse
[image]

and this is the proof

[image]

i dont understand this :

"$(c_i)$ has no cluster point since each $M^a=f^{-1}]-\infty,a]$ is compact "

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nondegenerate critical points must be isolated.

Comment: The fact that $M^a$ is compact is important ?

Comment: Yes ... In compact spaces, infinite subsets have limit points.